# Size limit of XML variable in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm passing XML into a stored proc.  I know the max size of the internal binary representation of an XML document is 2GB.  But does this limit also apply to xml variables that be held in memory while the sproc runs?

[EDIT]
Is the 2GB limit still relevant to SQL Server running in 64-bit mode which can use up to 7 terabytes of RAM?
[EDIT]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes it is the same as I read this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx

> You can **store** xml instances in a column, or a variable of xml type

and

> The **stored** representation of xml data type instances cannot exceed 2
>   gigabytes (GB) in size.

Highlights is done by me.

**Update**
The limit is the same for 64-bit OS.

Comment: Thanks - comment added to OP about 64-bit use.